# Why does searchFiles retrieve inexact matches?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a Google Apps Script function which converts some excel files to Google Sheets, in the process changing the filename to contain the current date/time in this way:

```
var theDate = curr_sec + "s:" + curr_min + "m:" + curr_hour + "h " + curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year;

...

var newFile = {
        title : name+' converted at '+theDate,
        parents: [{id: folderID}]
      };
```

Then, a little later on, I'd like to list all of the URLs of the newly converted files in a spreadsheet. I am currently finding the new files using searchFiles, in this way:

```
var filesConvert = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).searchFiles("title contains '" + theDate + "'");
    while(filesConvert.hasNext()){
...
}
```

This script works perfectly when it is manually triggered at an arbitrary time of day, only ever pulling the newly converted files which contain the current date and time in their filename, never the old files.

However, when the script is run using a time-based trigger at 1:00am, occasionally a seemingly random assortment of old files, which were converted days or weeks ago, will also get caught by the searchFiles function, and duplicates are placed into the list of URLs along with the new, non-duplicate files.

I suspect the problem has something to do with SearchFiles looking at the time of day contained in the filename and seeing matches from past runs of the script. For instance, if today's files contained theDate

`44s:7m:1h 7-4-2023`

then the script would also retrieve an old file containing theDate

`44s:7m:1h 23-3-2023`

Is there a way to address this problem?

Tried to use searchFiles for files with a name including the current date and time. Expected only files containing the current date and time. However, the same time from a past date may also be caught by the searchFiles function.

Comment: What about changing the process. And every time you edit a file name, you as well store the new name somewhere else ?

Comment: How about `var filesConvert = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).searchFiles("title contains '" + theDate + "' and title contains '" + theTime + "'");` ?

Comment: @BenoitDrogou thank you! That is a good idea. I will implement that and update with another comment if it seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: Try ```var filesConvert = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).searchFiles(`name contains '"${theDate}"'`);```